# Why special charactors got replaced when imported using 'require' in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, character-encoding, requirejs

I'm new to JavaScript and NodeJS. So please don't condemn me if this issue is obvious.

My `outsourced` file is a simple config file. Here is a short version of it.

`config.js`:

```
var config = {};
config.Web = {};

config.Web.Title = 'Title with öüöäéàè';

module.exports = config;
```

The `config.js` gets loaded into my `app.js` with that code:

```
var configread = require('./views/config/config');
```

All special-characters get replaced by a `�` as visible on console:

```
var WebsiteTitle = configread.Web.Title;
console.log(WebsiteTitle);
```

Strings defined in the `app.js` script itself doesn't have this behavior. So i think the problem must be in the way of loading my `config.js` into my app.

Does someone have a solution for this behavior?

Comment: This works as it should in my machine. Its printing the correct string `Title with öüöäéàè`.

Comment: You can read about this symbol at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block). It means your system couldn't render it.

Comment: Thanks @vibhor1997a for the fast responsing!
I would understand when my system would replace any special-characters. But the replacement happens only to strings coming from config.js. When i add an additional line like console.log('äöü'); in my app.js it gets printed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After some over-the-night-research i got the answer by myself.

The `config.js` file was created with Windows-Notepad. From there it got the ANSI-Encoding. It seems like NodeJS can't handle special-characters when `config.js` isn't encoded in UTF-8. I had to place the code in an UTF-8 encoded `config.js` file to solve the problem.

Thanks for any prior help!